# Removing /#divname with jQuery

Tags: jquery, url

I am using a [smooth scrolling plugin](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/)  for the navigation on my website but it adds #divname to the end of the URL (www.mysite.com/#div). I am wondering how i would remove this.

Thanks.

Comment: that how it is work. why you want to remove it ?

Comment: This seems like a feature, not a bug...

Comment: The plugin must not be displaying `name` attribute of the `div` instead its using the `id` attribute of `div`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `location.hash = target;` in the code (`$(scrollElem).animate` callback).  Note that the user will no longer get an entry added to their history, which may or may not confuse users, depending on your specific circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Comment the following line in the source:

```
location.hash = target;
```

I've not used this plugin before, so it's worth noting it may affect its functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line

```
 location.hash = target;
```